# Jenkins on K8s OIDC redirect behind Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, jenkins, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am setting up an Nginx Reverse Proxy, for redirecting all traffic from a domain into a kubernetes cluster via Port 30000. Kubernetes is gathering any workload and sends it to correlated services based on subdomains (using Istio / Virtual Services).

While this works well, I noticed some strange effects as part of Open ID Connect (Keycloak) redirects. Instead of utilizing Browser URLs, redirect URLs are Kubernetes internal DNS names and ports.

I would like to request your help, checking/correcting my Nginx configuration. My current example-issue is at Jenkins connecting to Keycloak, but redirect URL is incorrect:

https://keycloak.example.de/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=jenkins-client&redirect_uri=https://**jenkins-svc.jenkins.svc.cluster.local**/securityRealm/finishLogin&response_type=code&scope=web-origins%20address%20phone%20openid%20offline_access%20profile%20roles%20microprofile-jwt%20email&state=OGIxYWEzZGYtMmY1NS00

`Redirect_URI` should be `jenkins.example.de` but has been set to `jenkins-svc.jenkins.svc.cluster.local` (incorrect). Kubernetes internal service name is utilized for any reason.

**Nginx Configuration**

```
# Redirect Subdomains (incl. Web-Socket)
server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    
    ssl_certificate      /certs/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /certs/server.key;
    
    server_name ~^(.*).example.de;
    access_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/yourapp_access.log;
    error_log /opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/yourapp_error.log;
    
    # Security Limits (Connection slow-down)
    client_body_timeout 3s;
    client_header_timeout 3s;
    
    location / {
    
        # Security Limits
        limit_req zone=limit burst=100 nodelay; # or delay=15;
        limit_conn addr 100;
    
        proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header     HOST $http_host;
        proxy_set_header     X-NginX-Proxy true;
 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        
        # Keycloak
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
 
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443; # Hard-Coded as K8s Port was within variable.. :-(
 
        set $upstream redirect.example.de;
        proxy_pass https://$upstream:30000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the redirect was caused by Jenkins incorrect `Configure System`/ `Jenkins URL`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x3G6.png)